# Node.js app does not start when autoscaling on AWS

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have `Node.js` app on `AWS EC2` instance. This app consists out of 4 modules. To start my app from opened `SSH` terminal I use `PM2`and I run the following commands one by one:

```
pm2 start /opt/backend/app1/app1.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app2/app2.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app3/app3.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app4/app4.js
```

It works perfect when I run the commands above from opened `SSH` terminal. However, when I make an image from the `EC2 instance` and I configure launch configuration to launch new instances from that image and I add the following `bash` script that should be run when new instance is created, new instances are being made and auto scaling works but `Node.js` app does not start:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 start /opt/backend/app1/app1.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app2/app2.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app3/app3.js
pm2 start /opt/backend/app4/app4.js
```

I tried the following as well, but it still does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 start /home/username/opt/backend/app1/app1.js
pm2 start /home/username/opt/backend/app2/app2.js
pm2 start /home/username/opt/backend/app3/app3.js
pm2 start /home/username/opt/backend/app4/app4.js
```

Comment: Are you sure your bash script is executed ? Add a `touch /home/username/test.txt` to your bash script and ssh to an instance check if the file is there.

Comment: Be aware that userdata for startup scripts is run as root, whereas you may be running it as ec2-user for example. Also, check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` or similar to see if there's any console output logged from doing these commands